# linker input file unused because linking not done - gcc

Tags: gcc, linker, makefile

I am a beginner in writing makefiles. I have a makefile something like this:

```
PATH1 = /ref

CC=gcc
LINK = gcc

INCLUDES = .
INCLUDES += -I/PATH1/inc \
        -I/$(PATH1)/abc/inc/ \
        -I/$(PATH1)/def/inc/ 


all: src_file

run: src_file

src_file: 
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -MM  /ref/abcd.c -o $@ 

clean:
    rm -f *.o src_file
```

If I do a make, I get the error:

```
linker input file unused because linking not done.
```

I read some similar posts in stackoverflow but couldn't get a solution. Could anybody please let me know what's wrong with my makefile? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The culprit is the preprocessor option `-MM`. From [gcc pre-processor options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options),

> **-M**
>
> Instead of outputting the result of preprocessing, output a rule suitable for make describing the dependencies of the main source file.
> The preprocessor outputs one make rule containing the object file name
> for that source file, a colon, and the names of all the included
> files, including those coming from -include or -imacros command line
> options.
>
> **Passing -M to the driver implies -E, and suppresses warnings with an implicit -w.**
>
> **-MM**
>
> Like -M but do not mention header files that are found in system header directories, nor header files that are included, directly or
> indirectly, from such a header.

So effectively you are **just preprocessing** and hence no compilation and no linking and the resultant error.

Comment: Thank you Pavan for the reply. That makes sense. Thanks for the link, will go through the various options.