# 'linker input file unused because linking not done' error when running make

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, linker

I'm compiling C programs I made for a project.

### Goals

Compiling `get_next_line.c` and `get_next_line_utils.c`.

### Structure

I have 3 files, `get_next_line.c`, `get_next_line_utils.c` and `get_next_line.h` in my folder (excluding Makefile). Nothing more, nothing less.

### Code

```
NAME = get_next_line

SRCS = get_next_line.c get_next_line_utils.c
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

CC =        gcc
CFLAGS =    -Wall -Wextra -Werror
LIB_CRT =   ar rcs


all: $(NAME)

$(NAME) : $(OBJS)
    @$(LIB_CRT) $(NAME) $(OBJS)

%.o: %.c $(INCLUDE)
    @$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
clean:
    @rm -f $(OBJS) a.out
fclean: clean
    @rm -f $(NAME)

re : fclean all
```

### Error Message

`linker input file unused because linking not done`. I get this error several times.

I keep on running on this error when I run make. I followed another Makefile I had for another project, to no avail. I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486698/linker-input-file-unused-because-linking-not-done-gcc) article and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35103817/program-name-linker-input-file-unused-because-linking-not-done) one too but they aren't relevant to my issue.

Any input appreciated.

Comment: I downloaded your makefile and created empty `.c` files with `touch`. I get _no_ error. But, I note that you're trying to create a static library (normally ends with `.a`) but your target is a file _without_ the `.a` suffix. The `file` command says the output _is_ an `ar` archive, but !?!? It might help to remove the `@` prefixes so you can see the commands that are being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your makefile appears to be aimed at building a program named "get_next_line", but this is not altogether clear because what you are *actually* building is a static archive file with that (unconventional for an archive) name.  That's what the `ar` utility does.  With the gcc toolchain and many others, one would normally use the same front end (`gcc` in this case) for both compiling and linking.  That is,

```
$(NAME) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(NAME) $(OBJS)
```

... or, a bit DRYer ...

```
$(NAME) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

---

It is not clear why you are getting the specific message you report.  It looks like a message from the linker, `ld`, but I see no reason in the makefile presented to think that the linker would ever run.  As such, I am inclined to suppose that the message is associated with something altogether different.  Possibly you are running `make` in a different working directory, and therefore using a different makefile.  Or perhaps it is associated with some other command than `make` itself.  Or maybe you have an influential variable set in your environment that alters the meaning of your makefile.  Maybe you get that message when you try to *run* the archive as if it were a program (though that's not what I would expect to happen in that case).

Comment: I fixed the issue. I removed `-c` from `$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^` and fixed the underlying issue. It looks like I had duplicate files called `get_next_line_bonus` and `get_next_line_bonus` with the exact same code I forgot to remove. I also fixed the archive name.
You also mentionned running make in a different working directory, which I was doing. This is all fixed